# If $f$ is a function such that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f'$ has period $2\pi $.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, periodic-functions

If $f$ is a function such that $$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx=\int_c^{c+2\pi}f(x)dx \quad\forall c\in\mathbb{R}$$ and $f'(x)$exists for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then $f'$ has period $2\pi $.

I know I've to show that $f'(x)=f'(x+2\pi)$ for all  $\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I've rarely seen a more misleading title lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, after taking derivative for both sides w.r.t $c$, we have
$$ f(c+2\pi)-f(c) =0. $$
Changing $c$ into $x$ gives
$$ f(x+2\pi)=f(x). $$
Taking derivative for both sides w.r.t $x$, we have
$$ f'(x+2\pi)=f'(x). $$
Namely $f'(x)$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi$.

Comment: Maybe you should precise that you differentiate w.r.t. $c$...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.